# PHP 101 : How to call an external PHP file with action

Tags: php

I have a web app that needs to execute a PHP script. What I can do right now is :

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form metho="post" action="">
<input type="submit" value="CLICK ME"/>
</form>
</div>

<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this whole code is saved as a .php in my htdocs xampp folder. So when I run it, I get "Hello world" below my button.

What I'd like to do is save the script in my xampp and save an Html file somewhere else.

How would I call my script onclick of the submit button then ? I saw that I could set `action = "path to my php script file"` in the `<form>` tag but it does not do the trick. It says firefox is unable to resolve the address.

**Edit**

My actual code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="monstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="MyJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="map">
</div>

<form method="POST" action="C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php">
<input type="submit" name="" value="VALIDER">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "but it does not do the trick" - show us how did you try.

Comment: "set `action = "path to my php script file"`" is correct. Don't use the full path though, just the relative path - just filename if in same folder

Comment: @lolbas  I've edited my OP with the code I used

Comment: what happen if you do `<form method="POST" action="Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php">
<input type="submit" name="" value="VALIDER">
</form>`

Comment: @abhishekGurjar When I do that the browser seem to look for `test_connect_sqlsrv.php` in my project folder. So it says it cant find it. Then I put the file in my project folder. This time when I click THE WHOLE PHP SCRIPT gets printed on a new page ; just like that in PLAIN TEXT lol

Comment: @JasonKrs how are you running the code xampp,wamp check your php file if is missing something try to echo out in between code.

Comment: @abhishekGurjar I found the problem ...please see my answer. If you could edit it and explain why it worked and why it loads a new page instead of staying on the page where the submit button is would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found it. I needed to use an actual url...I guess. And since the file is on my computer, the famous combination "localhost:port_number" did the job.

```
http://localhost:8012/Mes_Scripts_PHP/test_connect_sqlsrv.php
```

-

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8012/Mes_Scripts_PHP/test_connect_sqlsrv.php">
<input type="submit" name="" value="VALIDER">
</form>
```

instead of

```
<form method="POST" action="C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php">
<input type="submit" name="" value="VALIDER">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: (method instead of metho)

```
<form metho="post" action="">
```

It should be

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: my mistake. Just a typo. But I'm added my actual code ...could u take a look at it

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php ---
PHP is server based, won't work on your computer hard drive.

Comment: comon I dont get it. I have xampp installed on my PC ... ie Apache is there. My PC is simulated that architecture. I dont understand your comment

Comment: Your PHP and HTML document both need to be in the htdocs/dashboard folder.

Comment: please see my answer. If you could edit it and explain why it worked and why it loads a new page instead of staying on the page where the submit button is would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'path.to.your.file.php';
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: not quite what I was looking for but THANKS. They are chances I'll use that later.

Comment: yeah, I didn't completely get your question right it seems. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

From you html code you want to execute a `.php` which is hosted in your server. You can do this setting the action of html form to the path of the `.php` in server.

You can try by something like this:

Replace `C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php`

By `localhost/Mes_Scripts_PHP/test_connect_sqlsrv.php`

Note, you are using `\`(backlash) while denoting the path. Try using `/`(slash) instead.

Comment: as I said, I did that but it seems to not work in my case. See my OP with the actual code I'm running

Comment: what is the url while saying firefox is unable to resolve the address?

Comment: The URL is the path to my php script file (the on in the html code) `C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php`

Comment: please see my answer. If you could edit it and explain why it worked and why it loads a new page instead of staying on the page where the submit button is would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to your latest edit.

`action` attribute that belongs to `<form>` tag should have one of the following values:

1. Absolute file path relative to server root folder, i.e.

   `<form action="/path/to/script.php">...</form>`
2. Relative file path relative to current folder, i.e

   `<form action="script.php">...</form>`, assuming it's in the same folder.
3. Absolute file path including website domain name, i.e.

   `<form action="//example.com/path/to/script.php">...</form>`

Comment: when I try 1. I get an error saying that firefox does not understand the address `C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php` (it becomes the address in my browser firefox address field) and when I try 2. I get the whole PHP script printed in the browser in plain text.

Comment: please see my answer. If you could edit it and explain why it worked and why it loads a new page instead of staying on the page where the submit button is would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JasonKrs in what way do you try 1st method?

Comment: I use the absolute path to my script  is `form action="C:\xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php"` When I use something like \xampp\htdocs\Mes_Scripts_PHP\test_connect_sqlsrv.php it doesnt do anything (I'm on Windows)...anyways I found that I needed to use a URL so `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8012/Mes_Scripts_PHP/test_connect_sqlsrv.php">` worked

Comment: @JasonKrs you missed one important part: `relative to server root folder`, not file system root.

Comment: Ahhh relative to server...in that case I don't quite know how I can do that since the server is on my machine

Comment: @JasonKrs there is no difference. At all. You server root folder is something like `C:\xampp\www\` or some additional folders if you made them. Hence, all absolute pathes (p.1) are assumed to be read from this folder.