# jquery ajax request result undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a string returned by my PHP. I call the PHP script from $.ajax and try to **put the string in a global variable** for further manipulation. It says the variable is undefined. Could you help me ?

(I used `dataType : "jsonp"` to avoid the error answered here [Ajax Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the))

My javascript (Jquery, Ajax, ...) script

```
var my_data;

function get_my_data(){

$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/My_PHP_scripts/test_1.php',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function (my_data){
        console.log(my_data);
    }

    });

}

$( document ).ready(get_my_data);
```

PHP script

```
<?php
$user = 'JOHN';
echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

PHP Script

```
<?php
$name     = 'JOHN';
$encoded2 = json_encode(array('name'=>$name));    
echo $encoded2;
die( $encoded2 );
?>
```

JS script

```
var my_data;

function get_my_data(){

$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8012/My_PHP_scripts/test_1.php',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function (result){
        my_data = result;
        console.log(my_data.name);
        console.log(result.name);
    }

    });
alert(my_data.name);
}

$( document ).ready(get_my_data);
```

Comment: Try `dataType : "json"`

Comment: remove the localhost part from the url. Browsers are strangely reaacting to this

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran  If I try that I get the following error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the I used jsonp as suggested there

Comment: @Toumash hmm I don't think this is a good idea. this address is the URL of my script in my xammp Apache server. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632325/php-101-how-to-call-an-external-php-file-with-action/37633316#37633316

Comment: @JasonKrs      You can either use `echo $encoded2;` or `die($encoded2);` but not both at the same time.....

Comment: @JasonKrs      By the way, why not use POST in your AJAX. Check out a Live Test here:  https://jsfiddle.net/1oemmv7h/

Comment: @Poiz  This is where it all started (before I arrived here).  My web server in on my local machine. So the url I'm using is `localhost:.....` Whith that kind of URL and datatype ='json' I get and error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the The only way to fix that is to put jsonp as data type. Now it seems that it's jsonp that bwill raise the `missing ; before statement` php error

Comment: @JasonKrs    Why don't you simply add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` at the top of your PHP File? It will also work JSON too.... The Answer we Posted below has now been updated to take that into consideration....

Comment: @Poiz Problem Solved. I really want to understand what happened here. Could you redirect me to somthing to read or a quick explanation will be great (so far I understood that PHP wasnt returning JSON encoded results and that, i was not allowing local POST request)

Comment: @JasonKrs The 1st issue was that you tried to echo a String instead of JSON. You solved that by json_encoding a key-value Array `json_encode(array('name'=>$name)); `. Then the next issue was Sandbox related. Bcos of the nature of your URL, Access was denied when you sent an AJAX Request to the PHP Script. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` solved that part. You can read more here: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting a valid JSON because your PHP Code was only encoding a plain string... why don't you try something like this in your PHP Script instead?

Your JS could be better like this:

```
function get_my_data(evt) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://some-domain.ch/test.php',
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(my_data) {
        alert(my_data.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Confirm this [HERE.](https://jsfiddle.net/1oemmv7h/)

```
<?php   
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   //<== ALLOW ACCESS TO ALL...
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   //<== TELL HEADER TO DELIVER JSON-TYPE DATA 

    $user = array('name'=>'JOHN');
    die( json_encode($user) );
```

Now you'd have a valid JSON Data and you can access it like so:

```
    my_data.name;    // WILL OUTPUT:  JOHN
```

**NOTES:**

```
    <?php 
        $name     = 'JOHN';
        $encoded1 = json_encode($name);    
        die( $encoded1 );         //<== RESULT: 'JOHN'           |==>[INVALID JSON - STRING]

        $name     = 'JOHN';
        $encoded2 = json_encode( array('name'=>$name) );    
        die( $encoded2 );         //<== RESULT: {"name":"JOHN"}  |==>[VALID JSON]
```

Test it out [HERE](https://eval.in/583536)

Comment: wow now I get a php error : missing ; before statement. In the console it  refers to ` {"name":"JOHN"}` Weird since there is nothing before that line. Also my_data is still undefined. I don't understand why this php error arises. Non sense....I used the $encoded2 part (just those 3 lines)

Comment: @JasonKrs please just update your post with your changes in order to we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Poiz  The php is bugging me mate lol (I think my browser is crazy). I only copied pasted what you gave me (I'm not even using my own arrays yet )...I still get the same errors ; that `missing ; before statement` and `my_data` is undefined. Please see the updated scipts in my OP

Comment: @JasonKrs Now we have an encoding problem too, if you are returning json string bases result, then you need to return the content-type header. To do this justo append header("Content-type:application/json"); before $name ... assingment and use "json" in the ajax's dataType

Comment: @Nico I can't use "json" as datatype because it raises an error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the Also I'm not just returning a strin but a PHP array object...kinda difficult

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your global variable *my_data* and the argument variable of your success function are not the same variable. You can change the argument name then assign its value to your global variable.

```
success: function (result){ my_data = result; }
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f6fdx26x/) fiddle to clarify this.

**Update:**
You also have the problem answered by @Poiz

Comment: nope. Just did that. Still the same. my_data is still undefined. `success: function (result){
  my_data = result;
  console.log(my_data);
 }

 });
alert(my_data);`

Comment: Yes, its true you have two problems. This one and the encoding problem answered by @Poiz